Achieve long exposures on live photos
Similar to this. Android phones have live photo feature but I couldn't found any way that can do live effects.

AFAIK, live photo is not a feature of Android but an addition of the manufacturer's camera app, e.g. Google Camera on Pixel devices.

@AndrewT. Galaxy phones also has similar feature, and I know that's a feature of the manufacturer's camera app, the manufacturer's library app also supports live files like that so they also support modifying the file
